# Hook into exceptions framework in CherryPy

Tags: cherrypy

I'm looking for a method to hook into the exceptions framework in CherryPy.  The reason for this is to be able to do custom logging with any exceptions raised by the application.  For example:

```
from cherrypy.exception import exception_hook, continue_to_raise

@exception_hook
def custom_exception_hook(exception):
    custom_logger(exception)
    continue_to_raise()
```

I know this is quite an abstract example, but basically I would like to catch all exception objects, forward them to something like Sentry and then continue with CherryPy's usual handler.  A bit like:

```
try:
    something()
except Exception as e:
    custom_logger(e)
    raise
```

I'm aware I could do this per error, but I'd like to do it in an efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: It's not exactly what you want, but: http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#hook-point . 
And there's also `request.error_response` and `error_page.default` for which you can define handlers (callables), like https://github.com/GDG-Ukraine/gdg.org.ua/blob/master/src/GDGUkraine/errors.py#L40

Comment: Using the `traceback` module, it's possible to get the call back within the `request.error_response` handler. I think this might be useful